# Can a Telegram bot display his own online status?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

Telegram can display when a user is online, like in this picture. Can a bot do this also?

Or maybe someone knows another fancy way to display, that the bot is active.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they cannot. Bots do not have an online status nor a "last seen" timestamp.

https://core.telegram.org/bots

Answer (score 0):

If you know when your bot will go offline - then before that you can change his name or description or something else to "Offline". And when it starts again - "Online".

But in general bot has no built-in ability for statuses.

Comment: @JanneckLange theoretically - you can. For example using `telethon` to send commands for that to the @BotFather